# PHP: how to achieve asynchronous effect for server script

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have searched the internet and see people are working their way to make concurrent calls with PHP even though PHP doesn't have rich concurrency features. I recently want to make improvement on one of my scripts on the server side, which takes a request from a client, gets some data from the database, returns the data and does some other data update.

The problem now is that the client have to wait for the server to get the data, finish the update and everything else, then it can finally get the result that it asked for. The client however doesn't care about the data update that the server does and therefore should not waste time waiting for it.

Through my study all other people are talking about the client making asynchronous call to the server without waiting for result, but I want the server to return data to calling client in the middle of its process.

If I do not want to change anything on the client side, is there any workaround that can achieve this effect??

Comment: Have you already looked into [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)?

Comment: @Satya ajax is for making request to server, but I am working on the server to make asynchronous response.

Comment: @mbosecke flush() is an interesting point, however I tried it and it didn't work, seems the server is still buffering the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about some pseudo multi-threading? http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254

Comment: Thanks for your posting but I have already done a google search and looked at that link... The problem is that data will not be sent to client until the whole script has finished, and forking another thread would not solve the problem since it's still contained in the same process as before...